# Workaround for AWS SAM with a provided lambda runtime

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli, aws-sam

I would like to stage a larger project with AWS SAM. Sadly a part of this project consists of a lambda function with a custom runtime and SAM does not include a way to set this up.

Does anyone know a workaround for this? If there is no other way I will try to set up the whole project with the wrong runtime and write a little function to change the runtime afterwards.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but what about publishing a custom runtime by creating a lambda layer for it? and then use it with the lambda function? SAM templates are translated into CloudFormation in the end so it could work as CloudFormation supports usage of custom runtimes.

Comment: Yes I can just do this in cf - thats the nice workaround I searched for. Thank you. Maybe I will just use cloudformation for the whole project.

Comment: @Junge Did you get a success running sam locally with custom runtime?